# Search through site pages over specific content in one of them

Tags: 2013, search, sitepages

Tried to find but couldn't. Is it possible to search through standard search engine for particular content and to find site page where that content is placed?

Comment: So do you have problems in findings results which should be e.g. written as texts on your site pages, or is the problem in limiting the search into pages so that e.g. lists are excluded?

Comment: the first option. when I search for exp. word Popocatepetl and I know it is in content of one of site pages I get 0 results.

Comment: Check the obvious stuff first: search service application (SSA) works in the first place, incremental crawl has ran since the site page with your content has been added, the pages are part of the scope SSA's crawls are active, SSA's app pool account has permission to your pages, etc. Try to verify a close-by case where the search works and make comparisons.

Comment: search works like a charm beside this "problem". it finds words from content in documents from doc libraries, etc. Will look little bit more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to write and close this topic months ago.
What we found out was that users created team site in which somehow they couldn't access Site Pages library, page kept sending to Home page. So they created pages in ShP designer 2013 in Pages library, not in Site Pages and they were creating Web Part pages not Wiki. After we transferred content from web part pages into wiki pages all pages were searchable.